# Binary Classification Encoding

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I am currently studying binary classification modeling, and have observed that two target classes are typically used to encode target labels: 0/1 or -1/1. Why are there two encoding classes and what are the pros and cons of each?

Comment: check my question above. People from statistics community like to encode with 0 and 1. and people from machine learning community like to code with 1 and -1.